# What would be the equivalent Eloquent version of this query with fallback to closure?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, closures

This is a example query. This is for MySQL.

```
select 
    sub_query.corporations_owned_id, 
    corporations_owned.corp_name, 
    sub_query.counts 
from corporations_owned 
INNER JOIN 
(
    select 
        corporations_owned_id, 
        COUNT(user_id) as counts 
    from corporations_owned_user 
    group by corporations_owned_id
) 
as sub_query 
on sub_query.corporations_owned_id = corporations_owned.corp_id 
where corp_status = 1
```

What I would like is to do is:

```
DB::table('corporations_owned')
-> select (DB::raw("sub_query.corporations_owned_id,  corporations_owned.corp_name, sub_query.counts"))
-> join ($query, callback_function () {
//what should be the equivalent closure here?
})
// rest of the query;
```

My expectancy for the callback function is:

```
-> join ($query, function($query) {
   $query -> //Another query in eloquent format only, but not in raw.
        "select 
            corporations_owned_id, 
            COUNT(user_id) as counts 
         from corporations_owned_user 
         group by corporations_owned_id"
})
```

I would like to add a callback to the join function in eloquent as I have shown in the above example. What changes to I need to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
->join(function($join){
    $join->on('a', 'comparison', 'b);
});
```

Comment: Something similar. But that still doesn't give me the clue to write the sub-query for join in eloquent.
I've edited the details. I think that would give you a clearer picture for my expectancy.

Comment: @PrateekShankar I think there's some confusion here as you're not using Eloquent anyway, you're using the Fluid Query Builder here. Anyway, the `$join` is passed here, if you need the query, then do a `select(function($query){ //$query->stuff });` here.

Comment: Yes. Something like this. 
Can you please give me rough code?
What I am wondering is: 
1. `DB::table('a')`
2. `DB::table('b')`

What I am tying to figure is how to do `DB::table('a') -> join(function($q) { $q -> {{ DB::table('b') -> select('x') }} } ); `